# ¿Como puedo evitar que Prepros me convierta a css los archivos parciales de sass?

Tags: css, sass

Actualmente estoy usando *prepros* para crear hojas de estilo más rápido, pero me he encontrado con el siguiente problema.

Cuando creo un archivo parcial de sass ya sea `_mixings.scss` o `_vars.scss` el compilador me los traspasa automáticamente a `_mixings.css` o `_vars.css`, por alguna razon no los obvia y los compila igual.

Comment: Bienvenido al sito ... !!! te doy la bienvenida y te invito a que realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Además revisa [ask] que te da información para realizar una buena pregunta y de esta forma obtengas buenas respuestas!. Es importante modifiques el formato de tu pregunta agregando lo que has tratado o investigado, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Los nombres de los archivos parciales de sass deben comenzar con un _

Prepros automáticamente lo detecta como partial.

2. Si no es asi selecciona el archivo sass y desmarca la opcion compile.

Comment: se te agradece la intención de ayudar, pero la pregunta tiene problemas de formato, por favor revisa lo que le dejaron en los comentarios, el OP debe mejorar mucho su pregunta

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en español. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender como funciona el sitio. Te felicito por escribir una respuesta, sin embargo te sugiero responder solamente preguntas bien formadas, pues con preguntas que están poco claras o incompletas se corre el riesgo de que el tiempo y esfuerzo invertido en responder se pierda cuando el OP edite la pregunta para completarla o hacerla clara. Para más información te invito a leer [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @element yo si lo entiendo, la idea es que los partials no generen css pero al OP si le genera los css para los partials

Comment: pero no crees que la idea es que le entendamos todos y no solo algunos? @RuslanLópez

Comment: no para responder, puede cerrarse la pregunta y reabrirse cuando le entiendan todos, pero ello no hace menos válida la respuesta

Comment: @RuslanLópez no he dicho que no sea válida la respuesta si te fijas por eso de hecho no la califiqué negativa, mi observación fue hacía la pregunta para tratar de orientar a quien respondió, pero la respuesta incluso por eso le dí un +1